# How to access Linux partition from Windows 10 WSL?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Windows 10 and Fedora installed on my computer in a dual boot configuration.

In Windows 10 Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), I can access my files in the Windows partition(s).

However, I can't find the equivalent of a /dev/sd* device within WSL.

Is there a way to access my files in the Fedora partition from within Windows 10 WSL?

This is what I see from WSL:

```
# cd /dev; ls -R1 | grep -v tty
.:
block
fd
kmsg
lxss
null
ptmx
pts
random
shm
stderr
stdin
stdout
urandom
zero

./block:

./pts:
ptmx
```

Comment: What do you see under `/dev/sd*`? Which is your Linux partition ? (you can see it with `mount` when you boot with Linux).

Comment: Have you tried installing Paragon's [Linux FS](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/linuxfs-windows/)?  Even if it doesn't allow WSL to access disk devices, it would still allow access to the filesystem (provided the Fedora partitions are an ext[2][3][4] variant).

Answer (score 2):

It seems Windows 10 WSL cannot access raw disk devices yet. See this [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/689).

Comment: @DanielAlder I see that you deleted your answer, but I think it's a totally valid, stand-alone answer.  When the question was asked, of course, only WSL1 existed, but with WSL2 and the recent `--mount` additions, the original request should be possible now, especially since the Fedora installation would be on a separate partition, right?  Tip, though - Don't start out with "little correction" on the answer (as you did).  Just say that this is an updated answer based on more recent WSL versions.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 11 WSL2, it is [possible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk) to access raw devices using `wsl --mount <DiskPath> --partition <PartitionNumber>` and `wsl --mount <DiskPath> --bare`, but only of a secondary disk (=not the boot device) which is a big drawback nowadays where everyone has a laptop with only one disk.

I tried to work-around using iSCSI or NBD with a [local server](https://github.com/cloudbase/wnbd) on host side, but failed because the compiled wsl linux kernel doesn't have these drivers embedded.

If I could find just any way to [access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108313/how-to-access-specific-raw-data-on-disk-from-java) `\\.\GLOBALROOT\ArcName\multi(0)disk(0)rdisk(0)partition(5)` or such from WSL2, I would find a way to mount it